# Selecting XML Element value using XPATH

Tags: xml, xpath

Greetings for the day.

I want to select the particular element value, when certain condition matches.

Here is my code:

```
<root>
  <companies>
    <company id="6">Tata Consultancy Services</company>
    <company id="7">Wipro</company>
    <company id="8">Infosys</company>
    <company id="9">Microsoft</company>
    <company id="10">IBM</company>
    <company id="11">Apple</company>
    <company id="12">  Oracle 
      <SubCompany>
         <company id="12.1">OracleSubCorporation</company>
      </SubCompany> 
    </company>
  </companies>
</root>
```

Here by, I want to select the tag value, whose value have to be "Oracle". Pls note that ,each element may have "n" level of child elements.

So my XPATH query is:

```
/root/companies/company/[normalize-space(text())='Oracle']
```

But i having error as "unable to evaluate query", while doing so.

May I kindly know, how to achieve this current query.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not an expert and been awhile since I used XPath but I think you can access all company nodes with //company? So you could get all companies called Oracle like //company[normalize-space(text())='Oracle']. May be wrong

Answer (score 0):

Your expression is invalid due to an *extra slash*:

```
/root/companies/company/[normalize-space(text())='Oracle']
                   HERE^
```

Demo (using [`xmllint`](http://xmlsoft.org/xmllint.html)):

```
$ xmllint test.xml --xpath "/root/companies/company/[normalize-space(text())='Oracle']"
XPath error : Invalid expression
/root/companies/company/[normalize-space(text())='Oracle']
                        ^
xmlXPathEval: evaluation failed
XPath evaluation failure

$ xmllint test.xml --xpath "/root/companies/company[normalize-space(text())='Oracle']"
<company id="12">  Oracle 
  <SubCompany>
     <company id="12.1">OracleSubCorporation</company>
  </SubCompany> 
</company>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra / in your XPath query, after company. The predicate (the part in []) should be of the company element itself, you are looking for company elements with a text content of 'Oracle' right?, so the predicate should be on the company element:

```
/root/companies/company[normalize-space(text())='Oracle']
```

You can access all companies i.e. also return sub-companies called 'Oracle' using:

```
//companies//company[normalize-space(text())='Oracle']
```